# How to use depenceny property in the style of tooltip to set the text?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, wpf-style

In a button, I am using a dependency property to pass information from the view model to the style of the button, so I can set the color of the color according to some conditions.

The code for the button is this:

The style in my xaml file:

```
<Style x:Key="BotonesColorEstadosTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="dp:BotonesEstadosAttachedProperty.CodigoEstado" Value="0"/>
                    <Condition Property="dp:BotonesEstadosAttachedProperty.AccionHabilitada" Value="true"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            </MultiTrigger>
        <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</Style>
```

The dependency properties:

```
public static class BotonesEstadosAttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CodigoEstadoProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CodigoEstado",
        typeof(short),
        typeof(BotonesEstadosAttachedProperty));

    public static short GetCodigoEstado(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (short)obj.GetValue(CodigoEstadoProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCodigoEstado(DependencyObject obj, short value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CodigoEstadoProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty AccionHabilitadaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AccionHabilitada",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(BotonesEstadosAttachedProperty));

    public static bool GetAccionhabilitada(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AccionHabilitadaProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAccionHabilitada(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AccionHabilitadaProperty, value);
    }
}
```

How to use in the button:

```
<Button Name="btnAlmacenesActualizar" Content="..." Height="23" Margin="3,0,0,0" Width="23"
    ap:BotonesEstadosDependencyProperty.CodigoEstado="{Binding CodigoEstadoActualizarAlmacenes}"
    ap:BotonesEstadosDependencyProperty.AccionHabilitada="{Binding EsAccionActualizarAlmacenesHabilitada}">
```

With this, I can use a property of my view model and pass to my style, that use the information in the trigger to set the color of the button.

Now, I would like to have a style for the tooltip, to have the default configuration for all the tooltips, and I would like to can pass the text of the tooltip at first, but later I would like to pass another variables. By the moment, to test, I would like to try with the text.

I have this style:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipDefaultStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="dp:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto"/>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My StackPanel with the tooltip:

```
<StackPanel Name="spTiposIva" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0"
            ap:ToolTipDependencyProperty.Texto="{Binding TiposIvaTooltip}">
    <StackPanel.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipDefaultStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel.ToolTip>
</StackPanel>
```

But in this case the text that is shown is "dp:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto". So I would like if it is possible to do the same than with the button, use a dependency propety to pass information from view model to the style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently not binding the attached property, you are assigning a **string** as `Value`. For binding to *attached properties*, you need to use the binding markup extension [and parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-path-syntax), e.g.:

```
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding (dp:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto)"/>
```

However, in your case you need to refer to the parent control of `ToolTip`, which your property is attached to. Normally, you would do this with a `RelativeSource` binding and `AncestorType`, but this does not work here, because `ToolTip` is not within the same visual tree as the parent control.

Instead, you can access the control via the `PlacementTarget` property on the parent `ToolTip`.

```
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.(dp:ToolTipAttachedProperty.Texto), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}"/>
```

Please also check your XAML for typos. The attached properties type does not match on the `StackPanel` and in the `ToolTip` style: `ToolTipDependencyProperty` or `ToolTipAttachedProperty`?